# Abstracting a date subtraction SQL query with Rails

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using the following as part of an ActiveRecord find method:

```
:conditions => "created_at > date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)"
```

This works properly on my development server where I'm using MySQL, but I'm deploying to postgreSQL which doesn't have a date_sub function. Ignoring the fact that I'm using two different databases, does Rails have anything built in to abstract this date subtraction operation?

If not, is there a recommended construct in Rails for specifying two different SQL queries that should be run in the event of encountering different DBs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
Object.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ?", 7.days.ago])
#=> SELECT * FROM "objects" WHERE (created_at > '2010-02-03 12:06:19.352398')
```

should work across different dbs

Comment: Was thinking about doing this but I was hoping to be able to use the database time rather than web server time.

Comment: I don't think it should matter that much when you are already using ActiveRecord :) On top of that this will work across dbs

Comment: I suppose it depends on the setup. It was my understanding that the created_at datetime was supplied from the database rather than the web server though. Is this not the case with ActiveRecord?